# SQL Order By with case when

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, case-when

I am trying to understand the **ORDER BY** with **CASE WHEN**.

My aim is to understand it fundamentally for that I had different use cases created

My base table is as below

```
|   Name |
|--------|
|    BPM |
|    BXR |
| Others |
|    XZA |
|    XYZ |
|    PQR |
|    ABC |
```

Query 1: Basic ORDER BY

```
SELECT * 
FROM City 
ORDER BY Name
```

Query 1 Result:Gave correct output as below(Name column sorted in ascending order)

```
|   Name |
|--------|
|    ABC |
|    BPM |
|    BXR |
| Others |
|    PQR |
|    XYZ |
|    XZA |
```

Query 2: I want `Others` at last

```
SELECT * 
FROM City
ORDER BY CASE 
         WHEN Name = 'Others' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END
```

Query 2 Result: I got partially correct result.I got `Others` at last but other `names` I expected it to be in ascending order.They actually appear the way they are in base table.

```
|   Name |
|--------|
|    BPM |
|    BXR |
|    XZA |
|    XYZ |
|    PQR |
|    ABC |
| Others |
```

I am also not getting what does `0` and `1` actually mean in the `ORDER BY` statement.

Query 3: I want `BXR` and `Others` at last.

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM City
    ORDER BY CASE
             WHEN Name = 'BXR' THEN 1
             WHEN Name = 'Others' THEN 2
             ELSE 0
             END
```

Query 3 Result: I got partially correct result.I got 'Others' and 'BXR' at last but other `Name` are not in alphabetical order.Same as seen in Query 2.Here also I am not understanding the significance of `0`, `1`,`2`

```
|   Name |
|--------|
|    BPM |
|    XZA |
|    XYZ |
|    PQR |
|    ABC |
|    BXR |
| Others |
```

Query 4: I want `Others` and `PQR` at top.

```
SELECT * 
FROM City
ORDER BY CASE
         WHEN Name = 'PQR' THEN 0
         WHEN Name = 'Others' THEN 1
         ELSE 2
         END
```

QUery 4 Result: I get `PQR` and `Others` at top but the remaining names are not in aplhabetical order.

```
|   Name |
|--------|
|    PQR |
| Others |
|    BPM |
|    BXR |
|    XZA |
|    XYZ |
|    ABC |
```

My assumption about `0`, `1`, `2` is that they are just numbers deciding the "order" in which a record should be.
(The record having 0 should be kept first and if all other records have 1 then should be sorted alphabetically)
(If there are '0', '1','2', in record with `0` should be first, record with `1` should be second all other record having `2` should be sorted alphabetically)

Correct me if I am wrong with this

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24403a/9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add name also in order by

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24403a/11)

```
SELECT * 
FROM City
ORDER BY CASE
         WHEN Name = 'PQR' THEN 0
         WHEN Name = 'Others' THEN 1
         ELSE 2
         END,name
```

OUTPUT:

```
**Name**

PQR
Others
ABC
BPM
BXR
XYZ
XZA
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just a quick question: Why do I need to add name explicitly when I am already specifying it in CASE WHEN

Comment: @sql_learner, cuase you need others names are in alphabetic order

Answer (score 2):

We can also `ORDER BY` using `FIELD`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM City
ORDER BY FIELD(Name, 'Others', 'PQR') DESC, name;
```

[image]

### Demo

The behavior of `FIELD` is such that it will return 1 for `Others`, 2 for `PQR`, and 0 for any other name.  So, we use a descending order to ensure that `PQR` appears first, followed by `Others`, followed all other names.

Comment: Thanks for an alternative approach

Answer (score 2):

You may keep the `name` column in the `else` case as :

```
SELECT * 
FROM City
ORDER BY CASE
         WHEN Name = 'PQR' THEN 0
         WHEN Name = 'Others' THEN 1
         ELSE Name
         END
```

*since always numbers has precedence over alphabets.*

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24403a/24)